# Sudo-io log output shows garbled text

Tags: ssh, logging, sudo

We have set up in our servers `sudoers` config the following configuration in order to log the console output for auditing purposes

```
Defaults:%administrators log_output
Defaults logfile=/var/log/sudo
```

This works in our servers except on one Debian 6 server

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 

$ cat /etc/debian_version 
6.0.10
```

Here is for example the output of a `ls` command in the home folder

```
$ cat /var/log/sudo-io/00/00/03/ttyout 
+-N��/VH�Q(�/.I/J-V��3PH�
                        ����+���rIG�F���8���)�g����g����d���*KG�*�Vd�pArb��~Yb�~N~�~qiJ�nf����@�8@,��@.�H�C_���*�K�$/�|70k���9��q6Pㄾ����n؆+�g���.��D{�, ����Q����ğ>�n�d�4��O�/{������)Ϟ��v�~��$,eZ�cQRgS]d��:��]u��^�����kd��|5}Jȳ��4>�,/6h`�|ͳ�^�,K�oӝ����u4����Msh����`'7���c
```

...

Is there any known issue we are missing that explains this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in this server the log files were being stored compressed using `gzip` as default.

The log files can be seen using `zcat` or `zless`.

Comment: please, choose this answer as a solution to help others.